Choice of initial state and angular dependence of spontaneously emitted light
I have a very weak understanding of spontaneous emission. I am trying to better understand spontaneous emission of an atom in vacuum and whether there can be favored directions for emission.
For example, suppose I have a hydrogen atom with the electron in $n=2, l=1, m=1$, and it spontaneously de-excites to $n=1, l=0, m=0$. On average, is there any angular dependence of the emitted photon? Or is it emitted perfectly isotropically despite the isotropy of the problem being explicitly broken by $m=1$ of the initial state?
